# How to migrate Code First changes to production

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I've been going through some tutorials and was comfortable with Entity Framework 6.xx where I created database tables, changes etc using migrations.

I deployed the database and then made more changes to local database by adding more tables, renaming columns etc.

How do I upload these changes for the database hosted on the production server?

So far I've been using database scripts and using database comparison tools but I feel I may be missing a trick if it can be easily done in a development environment by a couple of commands?

Comment: The description of the tag `entity-framework-migrations` seems to imply there's a migration tool built in to entity: "Migrations is a feature of Entity Framework that provides for detecting changes to a code(or database)-first model".  But your question makes it sound like you're not using it?

Comment: Once you start doing migrations then you should really use them for every change to your database schema. Did you use migrations to execute the changes to your local schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The recommended way to deploy migrations to a production database is by generating SQL scripts.

In EF Core: [Applying Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) or [EF 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/#getting-a-sql-script)

Or use for EF Core use [Bundles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#bundles).